# Doubles are contaminating my BigDecimal math

Tags: clojure

I'm writing a Mandelbrot Set explorer. I need as much precision as possible so I can zoom in as far as possible.

I noticed an unfortunate side-effect of mixing `double`s and `BigDecimal`s: they "contaminate" the type returned:

```
(type (* 1M 2))
=> java.math.BigDecimal

(type (* 1M 2.0))
=> java.lang.Double
```

I expected the opposite. `BigDecimals`, being potentially more precise, should contaminate the doubles.

Besides manually calling `bigdec` on every number that may come in contact with a `BigDecimal`, is there a way of preventing the auto-downgrade to `double` when doing math on `double`s and `BigDecimal`s?

Comment: sounds like a bug to me

Comment: nope, not a bug. it's this way on purpose

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future, note that my resolution problems didn't stem from a lack of decimal precision. My max iterations for the Mandelbrot algorithm was too low. I raised it to 200 from 50, and now even double precision gives a fair amount of zoom.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you introduce a `double` into the equation, you limit the amount of precision you can possibly have. A BigDecimal accurate to within a million decimal places is no use to you, if the way you got it involved multiplying by something with just 15 or so significant digits. You could promote the result to a BigDecimal, but you've lost a ton of precision whether you like it or not. Therefore, Clojure's promotion rules make that obvious for you, by giving back a double instead of a high-precision BigDecimal.

See, for example, [BigDecimal's JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) for an explanation of why it is a bad idea to convert doubles to BigDecimals, implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks. That might explain why despite using Bigdecimal everywhere, I still end up at a hard border that I can't zoom into. Now I just need to find out where I'm casting a double to a BigDecimal in such a way that it's limiting my precision.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't actually a bug, even though it at least looks wrong. To more clearly show how this leads to wrong looking answers compare these expressions:

```
user>  (* 2.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001M 1.0)
2.0
user>  (* 2.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001M 1.0M)
2.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010M
```

For the time being you will likely need to, as you suggest, make sure you only use big decimals in your program. It will likely be limited to the IO functions and any constants you introduce need the `M` on the end. Adding preconditions to functions will likely help catch some cases as well.